# Как передать значение из одной функции в другую

Tags: c

Есть такая программа, мне необходимо из функции `average` передать значение `average` в функцию `formula`, как я могу это сделать?

```
void average(int array[]);
void formula(int array1[]);


void main()
{
    int n[30], i;
    srand(time(0));
    for(i=0;i<30;i++){
        n[i]= rand()%200-100;
        printf("%d:%10d\n", i, n[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    average(n);
    printf("\n");
    formula(n);





    return 0;

}

void average(int array[])
{
    int i;
    double average, sum = 0, s, k;
    for(i=0;i<30;i++){
        sum += array[i];
        average = sum/30;
    }
    printf("The average is: %.2f\n", average);

    formula(average);


}

void formula(int array1[], double k)
{
    int j;
    double sum=0, f=0, deviation, formula[30];
    //k=average(z);


    for(j=0; j<30;j++){
        f += pow(array1[j]-k, 2);
    }

    deviation=sqrt(f/30);

    printf("The result of formula is: %.2f\n", deviation);


}
```

Comment: У вас `formula` принимает массив - как вы хотите передавать в нее `double`? Может, это должна быть какая-то *другая* функция?

Comment: могу ли я с помощью return передать значение average в йункцию формула ?

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @nick_n_a: Ым... Но `void average(int array[])` и `void average(int * array)` - полностью эквивалентны. Какой смысл менять?

Comment: @nick_n_a: Не надо выдумывать. Это записи поддерживаются С (как эквивалентные) со времен динозавров.

Comment: @AnT хорошо, удивлён

Comment: `formula(average);` не верная запись, можно создать массив на 1 елемент например, и передать в формулу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте `average` переменную глобальной. Напишите `double average;` после `#include...`, тогда она будет видна всем функциям.